# Receiving data all the time

Tags: c#, tcp

so made client-server-client tcp/ip app in c# that are supposed to communicate between 2 computers that are in different network.

I have few problems , first of them my server wont start on my public ip sayings its not valid in this context. Second is that I need to press send button twice before it sends data to server ,and then server 2 variations of data, one in bytes, other in char how its supposed to be. And third is how to make clients trying to receive data whole time. Should I have connection between clients have open whole time? I tried using timers to check if there is data to be received from the server.

Server code

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{
          TcpListener  server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.13"), 8080);


        TcpClient client = default(TcpClient); 
        TcpClient client2 = default(TcpClient)
        try
        {

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started...");



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server failed to start... {0}",ex.ToString());

            Console.Read();

        }

        while (true)
        {


            client = server.AcceptTcpClient(); /                   
            byte[]   receivedBuffer = new byte[1000];                

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Read(receivedBuffer,0,receivedBuffer.Length);               
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();                    foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)  
               {
                    if (b.Equals(126)
                    ) //proveramo  d                        {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());                        }

                }


            client2 = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            byte[] receivedBuffer2 = new byte[1000];
            NetworkStream stream2 = client2.GetStream();
            stream2.Read(receivedBuffer2, 0, receivedBuffer2.Length);
            StringBuilder message2 = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte g in receivedBuffer2)
            {
                if (g.Equals(126))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    message2.Append(g);
                }
            }

                stream2.Write(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);                      
                stream.Write(receivedBuffer2,0,receivedBuffer2.Length);                  
                Console.WriteLine(message2.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
        }
```

Client code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private int port = 8080;
    private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.13",port);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.13"), port);
        long byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(messagebox_TB.Text + 1);            byte[] sentDataBytes = new byte[byteCount];
        sentDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messagebox_TB.Text + "~"); 

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        stream.Write(sentDataBytes,0,sentDataBytes.Length);                       

        stream.Close();

        client.Close();



    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long a = 0;
        try
        {

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.13", port);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.13"), port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] receviedBytes = new byte[100];
            stream.Read(receviedBytes, 0, receviedBytes.Length);

            StringBuilder
                message = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in receviedBytes)                {
                if (b.Equals(126)
                ) //proveramo                      {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    message.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());                    }

            }

            textBox1.Text = message.ToString();
            client.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only have one connection with the following 3 parameters 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port Number.  When you use an IP address for the listener you end up having both the client and listener with the same 3 parameters and get an exception.  The is why you have a virtual port on a machine with IP.Any as the listener IP.  So change the IP of the listener and you issue should be solved.

Comment: At this moment I'm running this with local IP addresses so all address are same , because it fails to start a server using public IP address. My question is what should be start and what destination IP address . Also would this be easier if I have 2 clients directly connected ?

Comment: The work client means two different things depending if you are at the application layer or the transport layer.  At the application layer it is one node on a communication channel.  At the transport layer you have one client which is a server (also called listener) and other end a client.  You first start the listener which use an end point (virtual socket) called IP.Any.  You then start the client which connects to an IP address of the server.  The server and client IP must be different and that is why you use IP.Any in the server otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Its more clear for me now, much better explained than some tutorials. I will try to do it like this , and ill comment my results later.